# ServiceStack V3 vs V4

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I am trying to determine whether or not to start using ServiceStack V4 for development purposes.  I currently use ServiceStack V3 which I am pretty familiar with.  My question is though, what are the big differences, aside from licensing costs and ongoing support, between ServiceStack V3 and V4?  I know V4 added support for Async funcitons, and Ormlite has improved joining abilities, AutoQuery.  Is there anything else that would really be worth making the investment and switching from V3 to V4?  It would really be helpful to have a list of improvements and or side by side comparison between the 2 versions of the framework.

Comment: The [2014](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2014/release-notes.md) and [2015 Release Notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md) has a good summary of features added in v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features that are added in each release are now being maintained at: http://docs.servicestack.net/release-notes-history